# Dism unrecognized in CMD Shell in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, dism

I'm trying to enable dotnet 3.5 for a dependency for another application I'm installing. The problem is that my cmd shell that I'm using throws this error "'dism' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." but if I copy and paste the string that I'm passing to the cmd shell:

```
Dism /online /LogPath:C:\Users\HollyPlyler\source\repos\installerOptimized\installerOptimized\bin\Debug\\Logs\DSIMEnableDotNet.log /LogLevel:4 /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

It works fine.

Here is my CMD class:

```
 class CommandLineTool
    {
        public async Task Com(String command, string logName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("received " + command);
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + command;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;

            Task t = Task.Run(()=>process.Start());
            t.Wait();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            if (output.Contains("0/1"))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                installerOptimized.install.success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                installerOptimized.install.success = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            string success = installerOptimized.install.success ? "successful" : "unsuccessful";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Logs/" + logName +"_" + success + ".txt", output.Split('\n'));
            process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to run `cmd.exe /c dism ...` instead of just `dism ...`?

Comment: I could try that. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be working, but it takes awhile to complete. I'll let you know in a second.

Comment: Nope, just hangs forever. Doesn't work any of the other cmd commands I need either. So that /C is needed.

Comment: Did you look at the path environment variable in the cmd shell that's failing?

Comment: It's not the shell that's failing. It's running about 20 Chocolatey CMD calls just fine. It's just the Dism call that's failing.

Comment: Strange part is, I could swear it was working yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've gotten it to work in this way. By creating a second class for DISM.exe. I might merge them and add a varialbe latter to optimize.

```
 class Dism
    {
        public async Task Com(String command, string logName)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("received " + command);
           System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
           System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
           startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
           startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
           startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
           startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           startInfo.FileName = "Dism.exe";
           startInfo.Arguments = command;
        // startInfo.Arguments = command;
           process.StartInfo = startInfo;

           Task t = Task.Run(() => process.Start());
           t.Wait();
           string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
           if (output.Contains("0/1"))
           {
               Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
               installerOptimized.install.success = false;
           }
           else
           {
               Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
               installerOptimized.install.success = true;
           }
           Console.WriteLine(output);
           string success = installerOptimized.install.success ? "successful" : "unsuccessful";
           System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Logs/" + logName + "_" + success + ".txt", output.Split('\n'));
           process.WaitForExit();
       }
   }
```

Call it like this:

```
 myDism.Com("/Online /LogPath:log.log /LogLevel:4 /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All", "dism");
```

Thank you.